# Need to know what this theorem is asking

Tags: general-topology, advice

Theorem
Let (Y,$\tau_1$) be a a Subspace of (X,$\tau$)
If (X $\tau$) satisfies Second Countable axiom
Show  (Y,$\tau_1$) does too

My question is this : is this theorem asking us
to prove the hereditary of the Second Countable axiom?

Comment: That's right. ${}{}$

Comment: Looks like an exercise, not a theorem. Theorems don’t generally ask anything, they make declarative statements.

Comment: As a theorem: let $(X,\tau)$ be a second countable space. Then any $Y \subseteq X$ is second countable in the subspace topology.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is indeed asking to show that the property “$X$ is second countable “ is hereditary with respect to all subspaces.

Not that it helps with the proof.

Comment: Why the downvote ? It’s true, right?